# CSS trick to disable parallax effect on mobile

Tags: html, css, parallax

```
//html code for parallax - help required here.
```

I have added div for parallax with name parallax and parallax css in stylesheet. How can I disabling it for the mobile and desktop view? I had gone through numerous posts but no help.

But I don't want it to be disabled for desktop. I just want it to stop working for the mobile. Can something be done about it? when i use the media query it disables on my desktop but works fine on mobile.

```
        </head>
  <style>
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 989px) {
.parallax {
background-attachment: scroll !important;
}
```

Parallax code:

```
.parallax { 
    /* The image used */
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-image: url("images/teodorik-mensl-316897-unsplash.jpg");
    /* Set a specific height */
    height: 500px; 
    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>
<body>
//parallax declaration
<div id="PaperCall" class="parallax"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You said _"any help in disabling it for the mobile and desktop view will be appreciated"_ and _"but I don't want it to be disabled for desktop"_. Can you clarify where you want it disabled?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is known as a [**media query**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), which is denoted by wrapping your selector in 
`@media screen and (min-width: x)`. Anything within this `@media` tag will only get applied to devices matching the specified criteria (in this case, a minimum width).

Simply set the minimum width to correspond to the width of the smallest device you wish to include for the parrallax effect. A list of common devices and their corresponding widths can be found **[here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)**, but you'll probably want something like `480px`.

Here's a full example:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 480x) {
  .parallax {
    /* The image used */
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-image: url("images/teodorik-mensl-316897-unsplash.jpg");
    /* Set a specific height */
    height: 500px;
    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  //parallax declaration
  <div id="PaperCall" class="parallax"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: will this work for iphone? let me test and get back. thanks for prompt reply.

Comment: I actually I want the parallax effect to be there on desktop but disable for mobile? any help with that?

Comment: You can use `max-width` (instead of `min-width`) if you really want to. Perhaps a more appropriate approach would be to simply set `display: none` on `.parallax` inside of a `max-width` media query: `@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { .parallax { display: none; } }`.